# How do I show that the annihilator is a strict ideal of the ring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, ideals

I have the following definition:

> The annihilator of an element $x$ of an $R$-module $M$ is the ideal $$ann(x)=\{a\in R:am=0\}.$$

I now saw the remark that $ann(x)$ is a strict ideal of $R$ iff $x\neq 0$.

So I wanted to prove this. My idea was the following:

$\Rightarrow $ Let $ann(x)$ be a proper ideal and assume that $x=0$. Then $ann(x)=R$ which is a contradiction.

$\Leftarrow$ let us assume that $ann(x)$ is not a strict ideal. Then $1_R \in ann(x)$ this means that $1_R x=0$ so $x=0$ and it follows by contra position.

Does this works or is it wrong if not could you maybe tell me why? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument works, but I think this one is slightly cleaner.

$\Rightarrow$ If $x = 0$, then $r\cdot x = 0$ for all $r \in R$, so $\operatorname{ann}(x) = R$.

$\Leftarrow$ If $\operatorname{ann}(x) = R$, then $r\cdot x = 0$ for all $r \in R$, so in particular $1 \cdot x = 0$. Since $1\cdot x = x$, we have $x = 0$.

Therefore, $x = 0$ if and only if $\operatorname{ann}(x) = R$, which is clearly equivalent to your claim.